# Android EditText does not change text when setting gravity and a textwatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, gravity, textwatcher

I'm working in a custom layout with many inner EditText, when I set the gravity individually and also it has a TextWatcher then the values does not change.

```
public PinFieldView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setText(defaultValue);
    setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    setCursorVisible(false);
    setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}

private final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    ...

    @Override 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
      if (s.length() == 0) {
        setText(defaultValue);
      } else {
        setText(String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length() - 1)));
      }
      if (numberChangeListener != null) numberChangeListener.onNumberChanged(getText().toString());
      addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }

    ...
};
```

Not sure what is the problem, I'm testing on Android 5.0

Comment: PinFieldView is `FrameLayout`?

Comment: no, PinFieldView is an EditText